# Android Calculator EmptyStackException

Tags: java, android, user-interface, exception, stack

I want to make a Stack Calculator App. But when i entered 3 4 + , my App crashed and throws an EmptyStackException.

```
public class Calculator { // RechenLogik

 private Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
 private MainActivity activity ;

public Calculator(MainActivity activity ) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


public void calculate() {
    String expr =activity.getTextfromTextField();

        switch (expr) {
            case "+":
                stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
                activity.setTextField(stack.peek().toString()); // set Text
                break;
            default:
                stack.push(Double.parseDouble(expr));
                break;
               }
           }
        }
     And in Main Activity in OnClick Method 
 case R.id.button17: r.calculate(); TextField.setText(""); break; // Enter 
  press
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody  an Idea? Something must wrong with the stack  , but I can't find it.

Comment: Ok thanks, i have found the mistake.